# node.js реализация очереди

Tags: node.js, многопоточность, очередь

с веб интерфейса я делаю запрос на один из 16 адресов
затем выполняется не требовательная, но длительная задача и в течение часа слушаются все ответы от этого адреса.

нужно чтобы они выполнялись параллельно, соответственно если на данный момент все 16 адресов уже заняты, то запрос от следующего пользователя складывался в очередь. Как только один из адресов освобождается, то первый запросивший подключается к адресу.

мне не нужен готовый ответ, подскажите какие фреймворки лучше использовать под подобную задачу. возможно есть примеры

Comment: Да хотя бы **p-queue** - организует очередь

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал внешнюю очередь на rabbitmq. Запустил бы 16 процессов (по одному на каждый адрес) которые бы выгребали задания из rabbitmq.